# How to make each doc of a Firebase collection as ListTile?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-pageview

I have a code to display a list of images in a PageView with dots navigation. But for my project, I need to display several fields of the same document and this for each document of my Firebase collection. It seems that I need to put all my document as a List, don't know how to do that and can not figure out how to get each field of my doc then... Someone would have any idea ?

This is the code I use to display a list of images :

```
class SwipeImages extends StatefulWidget {

  final List imageList;

  const SwipeImages({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SwipeImagesState createState() => _SwipeImagesState();

}

class _SwipeImagesState extends State<SwipeImages> {
  
  int _selectedPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: 500,
      width: 500,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Stack(
          children: [

            PageView(
              onPageChanged: (num) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedPage = num;
                });
              },
              children: [

                for(var i=0; i < widget.imageList.length; i++)
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Image.network(
                      "${widget.imageList[i]}",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ), 
                  ),
                ),

              ]
            ),

            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              right: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [

                  for(var i=0; i < widget.imageList.length; i++)
                  AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(
                      milliseconds: 300
                    ),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
                    width: _selectedPage == i ? 30.0 : 10.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Black.withOpacity(0.4),
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 0.25,
                        color: Black.withOpacity(0.6)
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),

          ]
        ),
      ),
    );

  }

}


class DisplayImages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    CollectionReference images = firestore.collection('Images');

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: product.doc('My Document').get(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

          DocumentSnapshot<Object?> data = snapshot.data!;
          List images = data['Images'];
          // The field is an array with urls of the images I want to display;

          return SwipeImages(imageList: images);

        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keeping it simple, why don't you pass the whole document you get from the `FutureBuilder()`. This way, you can access all your fields(considering you have model classes, if not then you'll have to access fields using the `.data`) without having to make a network call again.

Something like this,

```
 DocumentSnapshot<Object?> data = snapshot.data!;
         
          return SwipeImages(doc: data);//now you can use the whole separate doc and access all the fields.
```

If you need a constant stream of documents (multiple documents), then you'll have to use a stream. More info on https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Using Streambuilder -

```
 StreamBuilder(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
      if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
          snapshots.hasData) {
        print(snapshots.data);
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
           
            return Text(
              " Do anything with the stream of data",
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: I do not have any issue to get my document data but to get the data for each doc in my collection... Actually, if I follow your exemple I'd get just one document's data... That's why I'm looking to make a List of all the documents my collection contains...

Comment: Oh that's simple, you need to use a Streambuilder for that, I've mentioned that in my answer too. Then, you'll need to use ListView.builder() constructor as a child of Streambuilder (). I've updated my answer.

Comment: ✌️, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
List images = data.get('Images');
```